# Some help regarding UIScrollView and changing ownership of a UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiscrollview

Basically, I'm working on an app on the iPad that involves a line which the user can scroll horizontally through on the screen. It's set up so that there is a UIScrollView and a UIView on top that uses drawRect. I also have a UIView that's basically a ball which I can move around via touch, and also detects when it is within the UIScrollView and when it is on the line that is painted in the UIView.

Here's my main problem, though. Both the UIScrollView and the ball are subviews to the same view controller, and I want to make it so that, when the ball is dragged into the UIScrollView, that it will scroll along with it and even disappear if need be. How should I do this? should I just make the ball a subview of the UIScrollView when this happens, or should I do it some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a container view. Put the ball in the transparent container subview and that is the view that moves around ( taking the ball with it). When you want the scroll view or line to move with the ball, insert them into the container at position 0 (under the ball).

Comment: Hmm....I'm afraid I don't quite understand the answer that you're giving. Do you mean to stick the ball on a little transparent subview that goes on to of the UIScrollView, or to insert the UIScrollView in that transparent view? I'm sorry for being so confused...

Comment: Put the ball into a container view, which becomes the view with gesture recognizers etc. When you need to add a view into it, to track the movement of the ball, put it into this view. Now the ball and the other view move in concert. iOS/OSX are filled with situations where using container views solves problems such as this.